# How install R if documentation doesn't work?

Tags: r, ubuntu-22.04

I have to install R on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04, i follow the documentation and even videos on Youtube of how to install... but it no one works :(

following the documentation, i have to put this command at the shell:

```
Sudo apt install r-base
```

and it should install all the dependence of R, but this happend:

```
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 r-base-core : Depende: libblas3 pero no es instalable o
                        libblas.so.3 pero no es instalable
               Depende: liblapack3 pero no es instalable o
                        liblapack.so.3 pero no es instalable
               Recomienda: r-base-dev pero no va a instalarse
 r-cran-kernsmooth : Depende: libblas3 pero no es instalable o
                              libblas.so.3 pero no es instalable
 r-cran-matrix : Depende: libblas3 pero no es instalable o
                          libblas.so.3 pero no es instalable
                 Depende: liblapack3 pero no es instalable o
                          liblapack.so.3 pero no es instalable
 r-cran-mgcv : Depende: libblas3 pero no es instalable o
                        libblas.so.3 pero no es instalable
               Depende: liblapack3 pero no es instalable o
                        liblapack.so.3 pero no es instalable
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

i tried to install each one individually, but it doesn't work

Comment: For a problem like this you might get better help at [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). And if you've tried to install the mentioned dependences like `libblas3`, I'd suggest including what you tried there and any messages that printed.

Comment: or askubuntu.com

Comment: try `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` and finally try `sudo apt install r-base` again; also check [instructions on r-project.org](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

Comment: I would expect that `apt install -s libblas3` would include more informative error messages (and similarly `liblapack3`). When you run them individually, what other errors do you get? (It'll likely be best to [edit] your question and include them in a new [code block].) Thanks!

Comment: Many of us run R on Ubuntu in for example 'continuous integration' (CI) at services like GitHub Action, often starting from a bare ubuntu container and installing. _It works_.  You must have somethings crossed: maybe you mixed an 'apt-sources' entry for focal with the one for jammy.  Double check, maybe start from scratch in a test VM or container.  It works. Reliably.  It will work for you too,  There is also a mailing list for R on Debian/Ubuntu:  r-sig-debian.